# How to print kable output to pdf in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf, printing, kable

I am trying to print tables to a pdf from a loop and am having no luck what-so-ever.  I originally was using Flextable but saw comments online that not being able to do this was a problem with it.  So, I switched to Kable and Kableextra.  I still am having no luck in making this work.  There are some threads out there that suggest various things.  I have tried them all and nothing seems to work for me.  So, I created a really simple example of where I am and I am hoping that someone will be able to show me how this is done.

This is RMarkdown code.

```
---
title: "test_print"
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

```
#create a list and put two kables in it
lst <- vector("list", 2)
lst[[1]] <- kbl(head(cars), booktabs = T)
lst[[2]] <- kbl(head(pressure), booktabs = T)
```

```
lst[[1]]  #this code works fine producing a table in the pdf file
```

```
for (i in 1:2)
{
  lst[[i]]   #this code produces no output at all
}
```

```
#this produces a shiny tag list with the reports seemingly there but they do not output properly
for (i in 1:2)
{
  print(lst[[i]])  
}
```

There have been various suggestions online for how to fix this but I have not been able to get any to work.  For instance, in several places it says that you have to wrap the kable in print as the side effects do not work properly in a loop.

I am new to R and RMarkdown, so I could be missing something simple here, but enough other people have had problems with this as well (given the threads I found) so perhaps it is not so simply after all.

I would appreciate and ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: You just need to include `results = 'asis'` in the RMarkdown chunk. For more details, please see [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#generate-multiple-tables-from-a-for-loop).

Comment: Thanks, I had found this before but somehow I never got the right combination of things put together--see my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with an answer to my own question, and since I had trouble sorting through all of the various "answers" to this I found online I thought I would give the answer that worked for me here.  It is a combination of the suggestions that were out there.

```
---
title: "test_print"
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

```
lst <- vector("list", 2)
lst[[1]] <- kbl(head(cars), booktabs = T)
lst[[2]] <- kbl(head(pressure), booktabs = T)
```

```
for (i in 1:2){
  print(lst[[i]])
  cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
}
```

The keys were wrapping the kable in a print statement, adding results='asis' to the chunk header, and then adding the `cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")` statement after the print.

I had seen the suggestion of adding in just `cat("\n")` a number of times, but this does not work--at least not in a pdf.  I needed to force a pagebreak after each table and this works for me.

Now I have a new problem.  While this works in the simplified example with only 2 tables, my actual code has 63 tables that need to be printed.  I am now getting a LaTeX error saying that I have too many unprocessed floats.  I tried limiting the tables printed out (to 5) and it worked fine, so it is definitely the number of tables that is the problem.
Looking into a fix for that but if anyone knows the answer please pass it along.  I know I am not supposed to ask questions here and if I can't find the answer I will certainly ask it properly in another question.  Just figured if you had read this far you might be able to help.

Comment: The last answer was easy enough to find.  I needed to increase the number of floats available as the default is less than the number of reports I am creating.  I used the command `\extrafloats{200}` and my reports now output properly.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
  
# Database

storms <- head(storms, 100)

#Create a function with the format of your table

func.table <- function(x) {

  flextable(x) %>% 
    theme_vanilla() %>% 
    align_text_col(align = "center") %>% 
    padding(padding = 1, part = "all") %>% 
    bold(part = "header") %>% 
    line_spacing(space = 1, part = "all")

}

# Create a list
list.storms <- storms %>% 
  group_by(status) %>% 
  tidyr::nest()

# Apply function to list
tab.results <- map(list.storms$data,func.table)

# Results
tab.results
```